# Namespace in XmlDocument

Tags: xml-namespaces, xmldocument

The question is..... is this still the best way to do this?

I have an XML file with this line near the top:

```
<bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:es="abcd.xsd"
                      xmlns:un="utranNrm.xsd"
                      xmlns:xn="genericNrm.xsd"
                      xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd">
```

and in my program (that is working) I have:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"SampleBig.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("es", "abcd.xsd");
manager.AddNamespace("un", "utranNrm.xsd");
manager.AddNamespace("xn","genericNrm.xsd");
manager.AddNamespace("gn","geranNrm.xsd");
```

What I'm not understanding is why the Namespace code is even necessary. The information I add is the same info in the top of the XML file. Apparently, .NET doesn't pay attention to it when the XML file is loaded. Is that so?

And as I started out, in general, is this still the best way to do this?

Chuck

Comment: *Best* in what regard? Do you understand what namespaces are for, and how they're useful in validating the XML?

Comment: In basic terms, yes. My question is more about getting the namespace info into the program. Is there now a way where .NET grabs the info from the XML file, since it is already there? Or do we still have to add the namespace info that looks redundant to what's in the file? I don't think it would save anything for my program to read the namespace info from the xml file and add it based on that. I just don't know if there is a newer way to deal with this.